# TypeScript / Angular 2 creating a dynamic object deserializer

Tags: json, angular, typescript

So I am coming from a background of C# where I can do things in a dynamic and reflective way and I am trying to apply that to a TypeScript class I am working on writing.
Some background, I am converting an application to a web app and the backend developer doesn't want to change the backend at all to accommodate Json very well. So he is going to be sending me back Json that looks like so:

```
{
 Columns: [
  {
   "ColumnName": "ClientPK",
   "Label": "Client",
   "DataType": "int",
   "Length": 0,
   "AllowNull": true,
   "Format": "",
   "IsReadOnly": true,
   "IsDateOnly": null
  }
 ],
 Rows:[
  0
 ]
}
```

I am looking to write an Angular class that extends Response that will have a special method called JsonMinimal which will understand this data and return an object for me.

```
import { Response } from "@angular/http";

export class ServerSource
{ 
    SourceName: string;
    MoreItems: boolean;
    Error: string;
    ExtendedProperties: ExtendedProperty[];
    Columns: Column[];
}    

export class ServerSourceResponse extends Response
{ 



    JsonMinimal() : any
    { 

        return null; //Something that will be a blank any type that when returned I can perform `object as FinalObject` syntax
    }


}
```

I know StackOverflow isn't for asking for complete solutions to problems so I am only asking what is one example taking this example data and creating a dynamic response that TypeScript isn't going to yell at me for. I don't know what to do here, this developer has thousands of server-side methods and all of them return strings, in the form of a JSON or XML output. I am basically looking for a way to take his column data and combine it with the proper row data and then have a bigger object that holds a bunch of these combined object.

A usage case here after that data has been mapped to a basic object would be something like this.
Example:

```
var data = result.JsonMinimal() as LoginResponse; <-- Which will map to this object correctly if all the data is there in a base object.

var pk = data.ClientPK.Value;
```

Comment: Why are you doing `var finalObject = Object.assign({}, rawObject);`?. Also, what is `LoginResponse`? I think you may be overcomplicating things here, but it is not quite clear to me, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I haven't really started on anything with the code that was a first thought not anything useful I will remove it from the code example.

Comment: Note that your function named `JsonMinimal()` is not returning JSON, but rather an object. JSON is a string format.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure I understand, but you may want to try a simple approach first. Angular's http get method returns an observable that can automatically map the response to an object or an array of objects. It is also powerful enough to perform some custom mapping/transformation. You may want to look at that first.

Here is an example:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here I'm mapping a json response to an array of Product objects I've defined with an IProduct interface. Since this is just a "lambda" type function, I could add any amount of code here to transform data.